# Image streching when compose is being made in Android

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, coil

I have issue that image is stretched for 1 second and then comes back as is should be.
Im using Coil and Compose.

```
            topBar = {
                TopAppBar(
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(
                        top = (0.03 * screenHeightDp),
                        start = (0.08 * screenWidthDp),
                        end = (0.08 * screenWidthDp)
                    ),
                    elevation = 0.dp,
                    title = {
                        Row(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .fillMaxWidth()
                                .height(32.dp)
                                .padding(end = 0.08 * screenWidthDp),
                            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
                        ) {
                            val logoPath =
                                context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
                                    .toString() + "/logo_image.svg"
                            ImageComponent(
                                imagePath = logoPath,
                                contentDescription = "logo",
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .fillMaxWidth(),
                                maxHeight = 32
                            )
                        }
                    },
```

And image component:

```
    val painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(
        model = ImageRequest.Builder(context = LocalContext.current)
            .data(imgFile)
            .decoderFactory(SvgDecoder.Factory())
            .error(fallbackImageResource)
            .build()
    )

    Image(
        painter = painter,
        contentDescription = contentDescription,
        modifier = modifier.height(maxHeightImage.dp),
```

How to prevent image (.svg) streching